# An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, core-data, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to use core data inside an iphone application, but when I launch the application I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext'
```

The code is this:

```
#import "CocktailController.h"

@implementation CocktailController

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize cocktailDetailController;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController=fetchedResultsController_, managedObjectContext=managedObjectContext_;

#pragma mark Instance Methods

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"name"] description];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Cocktails";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [fetchedResultsController_ release];
    [managedObjectContext_ release];
    [tableView release];
    [cocktails release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
    }
    Cocktail *cocktail = [cocktails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = cocktail.name;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController_ != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController_;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cocktail" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fetchedResultsController_ performFetch:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return fetchedResultsController_;
}    


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller delegate


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

It is inside a tabbar application (and has a navigation controller)

Thanks

```
@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you are setting the managed object context properly?
From what I can see there, the Fetch Request is being created properly, but you don't set the context in that class. Do you set the context in another class before you show the view?

Usually I keep the context in the application delegate, and then set the class' context in viewDidLoad, or fetchedResultsController like so:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;
```

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

A good way to do that without having to include AppDelegate dependency in any controller where you're going to use the managedObjectContext is by passing the object to the controller when the application finished launching.

In AppDelegate.m, method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions do the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    YourController  *controller = (YourController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    return YES;
}
```

Make sure you have the property managedObjectContext on your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Its a late reply but i had exactly the same problem last day so according to my code:

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

I was putting above line of code after following line:

```
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"author" cacheName:nil];
```

So the build was coming up with errors. So what i understood, Sort descriptors must be set to fetch request before assigning the fetch request to Fetched Results Controller.

Putting it at right place solved my problem. Hope this helps anyone else who faces the situation.